# APPlication scraping with Python how to?

Tags: python, web-scraping

need to start app scraping, what tools do i need?
where to start?
I can do web scrapping but i do not have any idea how to scrape apps android or ios

any help is appreciated

Comment: Search the internet for a tutorial. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this can help you.

1. Which kind of app do you want? Try to download the apk (it is the .exe file of android) from here https://apkpure.com/
2. After that from this link https://www.alphr.com/how-to-run-apk-files-windows-10-device/ follow the steps of Running an APK File Using ARC Welder
3. Then you will have the app on your laptop
4. After that with a sniffer like https://www.telerik.com/fiddler you can see all the requests that the app is making
5. In this request is the information that you want
6. You can simulate the request and obtain the information another time